# strftime('%-d') fails on heroku web dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, strftime

On heroku, rails rendering on my web dynos gives me

```
Time.now.strftime('%a, %b %-d')
=> "Wed, Mar -d"
```

Running heroku console gives me the expected behavior

```
Time.now.strftime('%a, %b %-d')
=> "Wed, Mar 13"
```

I have a monkeypatch that fixes it, but I'd be interested if anyone has a cleaner solution

Comment: I get correct output on my Heroku console.  What Ruby versions are involved?  Are you using any gems that mess with `Time`?

Comment: Here's what I get on Heroku, vanilla Rails 3.2.12 app - http://salty-castle-4402.herokuapp.com/demo/index - I thought it might be a quotes issue but I can't duplicate it.